# Python write to a text file after certain column

Tags: python, string, formatting

I am using the following code:

```
f.write(str(foo) + '            ' + str(bar) + '\n')
```

The problem is that the number of letters in `foo` is different for each value and I get the following output:

```
Account Category            DORMANT
Last Made Update            21/12/2013
Mortgages Partly Satisfied          0
```

The problem is that because I am using same amount of space (`'         '`) for all the values and  `Mortgages Partly Satisfied` is longer string, so the value `0` goes to the right. What I would like the output to be is:

```
Account Category            DORMANT
Last Made Update            21/12/2013
Mortgages Partly Satisfied  0
```

My question is: Is there a way to insert the second value `bar` after certain amount of columns so the values will always be aligned?

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: learn [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/) - ie. [Padding and aligning strings](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to use string formatting with the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method, like so:

```
items = [
    ('Account Category', 'DORMANT'),
    ('Last Made Update', '21/12/2013'),
    ('Mortgages Partly Satisfied', '0'),
]
for label, value in items:
    f.write('{:28} {}\n'.format(label, value))
```

The `:28` is the width specifier. See [format string docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Python lets you add padding for strings by specifying the number of characters a given field should use. This can be used when writing to your file as follows:

```
data = [["Account Category", "DORMANT"], ["Last Made Update", "21/12/2013"], ["Mortgages Partly Satisfied", "0"]]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for v1, v2 in data:
        f.write("{:28} {}\n".format(v1, v2))
```

Giving you:

```
Account Category             DORMANT
Last Made Update             21/12/2013
Mortgages Partly Satisfied   0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `ljust` function, that returns the string left justified.

Just, try it:

```
f.write(str(foo).ljust(40) + str(bar) + '\n')
```

You can also check other methods in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust)

This is going to give you the next output:

```
Last Made Update                        21/12/2013
Account Category                        DORMANT
Mortgages Partly Satisfied              0
```